# SSRS - Cannot read the next row for dataset DataSet1

Tags: sql, t-sql, reporting-services, ssis, ssrs-2017

```
with TotCFS as (select count(*)*1.0 as TotalCFS,
 'Total CFS' as RowTitle
from PrivilegeData.TABLENAMEC c
where cast(CallCreatedDateTime  as date) between @StartDate and @EndDate and CallPriority in ('1', '2', '3', '4', '5') and AreaCommand in ('FH', 'VA', 'NE', 'NW', 'SE', 'SW')  and IsBolo = 0
) 


select AreaCommand, CallPriority, 
avg(datediff(second, CallCreatedDateTime, CallEntryDateTime)) as AverageSeconds,
left(dbo.[ConvertTimeToHHMMSS](avg(datediff(second, CallCreatedDateTime, CallEntryDateTime)), 's'), 7) as DisplayAvg,
 'Create to Entry' as RowTitle, 1 as RowSort, b.SortOrder as ColumnSort
from PrivilegeData.TABLENAMEC c
inner join (select distinct AreaCommandAbbreviation, SortOrder from dimBeat) b on c.AreaCommand = b.AreaCommandAbbreviation
where cast(CallCreatedDateTime  as date) between @StartDate and @EndDate and CallPriority in ('1', '2', '3', '4', '5') and AreaCommand in ('FH', 'VA', 'NE', 'NW', 'SE', 'SW')  and IsBolo = 0
group by AreaCommand, CallPriority, SortOrder

UNION

select AreaCommand, CallPriority, 
avg(datediff(second, CallEntryDateTime, CallDispatchDateTime)) as AvgEntryToDispatchSeconds,
left(dbo.ConvertTimeToHHMMSS(avg(datediff(second, CallEntryDateTime, CallDispatchDateTime)), 's'), 7) as DisplayAvgEntryToDispatchSeconds,
 'Entry to Dispatch' as RowTitle, 2 , b.SortOrder
from PrivilegeData.TABLENAMEC c
inner join (select distinct AreaCommandAbbreviation, SortOrder from dimBeat) b on c.AreaCommand = b.AreaCommandAbbreviation
where cast(CallCreatedDateTime  as date) between @StartDate and @EndDate and CallPriority in ('1', '2', '3', '4', '5') and AreaCommand in ('FH', 'VA', 'NE', 'NW', 'SE', 'SW')  and IsBolo = 0
group by AreaCommand, CallPriority, SortOrder
```

I have about 8 unions I'm doing for this code. the difference is the name of the Row titles. this report has been running for about a year without any problems. I use this code in SSRS query type text. I also have one of my rowset name 'AverageSeconds' configured to read this expression

```
 =IIf((Fields!RowSort.Value) < 7,Format(DateAdd("s", Avg(Fields!AverageSeconds.Value), "00:00:00"), "H:mm:ss"), Sum(Fields!AverageSeconds.Value))
```

the report some how broke and I have tried everything I find searching to fix it. Please help me with this error 'rsErrorReadingNextDataRow'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This has got to be an issue with the data being operated upon.  Maybe a 0 or NULL value condition..  I would start with reviewing records that were added or changed around the time that the problem began.

Comment: I agree, you might have a null somewhere in there

Answer (score 0):

I Dropped and recreated the fact table and run my ssis package, which seams to fix it. The reason I did that is because I couldn't find a NULL or 0 value.